# Open webpage via TextView

Tags: android, textview

I've defined the following TextView:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/card12"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_card_background"
    android:text="Go to Google"/>
```

And I'd like to open a `webpage` when c`licking the TextView` (which shows a `text` instead of the full `url`)

I've read a lot about this, but all the thing I've tried doesn't work for me. I've tried writing `android:autoLink="web"` and `view.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());` but this doesn't make the `TextView clickable`. I also tried via `intent` but for this I'd have to use `Button` instead of `TextView`.

Also say that I'm not using `Activity`, I'm using `Fragment`:

```
public class InformationFragment extends Fragment {

public InformationFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.information_layout, container, false);

    return rootView;
}
}
```

Any ideas about how to do this? Thank you so much.

Comment: Add android:clickable="true" to your textView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
TextView link = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.card12);
link.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"http://google.com\">Go to Google</a>"));
link.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: One more question.. is there a way to change the color and remove the underline? Thanks

Comment: Add style=\"text-decoration:none\" to your <a> tag.